How to cross-account Public AWS MSK through IAM
What is the secrets to corss-account AWS MSK through IAM? At the moment, I do have a running AWS MSK cluster and I am able to connect to it as well as publish and consume messages from it, while the ECS task is running in the same account as AWS MSK.
The moment I move ECS task to different account, I am not able anymore to authenticate, and I am being provided with following error
SaslAuthenticator-OAUTHBEARER: SASL OAUTHBEARER authentication failed
Is there a place, where can I specify which accounts are allowed to do an IAM authentication?
The IAM policies I am using, do not specify any AWS account or ECS task roles, so I understand this behaviour might expected, otherwise anyone could just allow themselves just by specifying my cluster/topic ARNs in their ecs-task policy
Cheers

I have just noticed, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423783/connect-to-amazon-msk-from-a-client-in-another-account?rq=2 is trying to resolve the same problem
